# Why won't my Perl function work?

Tags: perl, function, pass-by-reference

I am having trouble with a function I wrote...

```
sub TemplateReplace
{
    my($regex, $replacement, $text) = @_;
    $text =~ s/($regex)/($replacement)/gs;
}

my $text = "This is a test.";
TemplateReplace("test", "banana", $text);
```

But it doesn't work. I thought arguments were sent by reference in Perl. Does the line `my($regex, $replacement, $text) = @_;` then copy them? How do I fix this?

Comment: Before we figure out how to fix it, you have to explain what you want to happen. Do you want to change the original variable, or get a new string that shows the modifications? It's the difference between Chas. and Adnan's answers. :)

Comment: If you are trying to edit the passed argument magically, then Chas's answer is the one you are looking for. If you'd rather do it the "Right Way", follow Adnan's. Changing variables from afar is generally frowned upon, it usually just increases complexity with little benefit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are modifying a copy of the `$text` you passed in; this will have no effect on the original.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $text = "This is a test.";

template_replace(qr/test/, "bannana", $text);

print "$text\n";

sub template_replace {
    my $regex       = shift;
    my $replacement = shift;
    $_[0] =~ s/$regex/$replacement/gs;
}
```

The code above works because the elements of @_ are aliased to the variables passed in.  But [Adnan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740443/why-wont-my-perl-function-work/740455#740455)'s answer is the more commonly done.  Modifying arguments passed into functions is surprising behavior and makes things like `template_replace(qr/foo/, "bar", "foo is foo")` not work.

Answer (score 10):

```
sub TemplateReplace
{
   my($regex, $replacement, $text) = @_;
   $text =~ s/($regex)/($replacement)/gs;
   return $text;
}

 my $text = "This is a test.";
 $text = TemplateReplace("test", "banana", $text);
```

There. That should work.

And yes, your my( ..) = @_ does copy the args. So if you're modifying a variable, you need to return it unless it's a global.

Comment: +1 for a correct method, though Chas. Owens's answer helped me understand more.

Answer (score 4):

It's the "assignment" part of the sub-routine that is making the copies of the data.

If you modify the @_ arguments directly, they work as you expect.  It is however, not very readable. :-)

```
use strict;
umask(0);
$|=1;
my $debug = 0;

my $text = "This is a test.";

print "Before 1: [$text]\n";
TemplateReplace("test", "banana", $text);
print "After 1: [$text]\n";

print "Before 2: [$text]\n";
TemplateReplace2("test", "banana", $text);
print "After 2: [$text]\n";

sub TemplateReplace
   {
   my ($regex, $replacement, $text) = @_;    

   $text =~ s/($regex)/($replacement)/gs;
   }

sub TemplateReplace2
   {
   $_[2] =~ s/$_[0]/$_[1]/gs;
   }
```

returns:

```
Before 1: [This is a test.]
After 1: [This is a test.]
Before 2: [This is a test.]
After 2: [This is a banana.]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variation on how to do it, which is almost identical to your code with a slight difference.

```
use strict;
use warnings;


sub TemplateReplace {
    my($regex, $replacement, $text) = @_;
    $$text =~ s/($regex)/$replacement/gs;
}



my $text = "This  is a test."; 
TemplateReplace("test", "banana", \$text);
print $text;
```

This behavior is *explicit* instead of *implicit*. In practice, it works identically to [Chas. Owens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740443/why-wont-my-perl-function-work/740485#740485) result, but uses scalar-refs instead of relying on understanding the behaviour of arrays.

This will make it more obvious to anybody reading your code that the function "TemplateReplace" is *intentionally* modifying $text.

Additionally, it will tell you you're using it wrong by squawking with :

```
Can't use string ("This  is a test.") as a SCALAR ref while "strict refs" in use at replace.pl line 9.
```

If you happen to forget the \ somewhere.